# Is is possible to apply a generic method to a list of items?

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say I've written my own method to reverse a list in place.

```
public static void MyReverse<T>(List<T> source)
{
    var length = source.Count;
    var hLength = length / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < hLength; i++)
    {
        T temp = source[i];
        source[i] = source[length - 1 - i];
        source[length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

I call it like so, and it works.

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>();
MyReverse(fooList);
```

If I want to reverse multiple lists, I call it like so.

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>();
var barList = new List<Bar>();
var bazList = new List<Baz>();
MyReverse(fooList);
MyReverse(barList);
MyReverse(bazList);
```

If I want to reverse an arbitrary number of lists, I'd try:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lists = new List<object>
    {
        new List<Foo>(),
        new List<Bar>(),
        new List<Bar>()
    };

    ReverseLists(lists);
}

public static void ReverseLists(List<object> sourceLists)
{
    foreach (var sourceList in sourceLists)
    {
        MyReverse(sourceList); // Error: Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage
    }
}
```

But this throws a compile time error. Is what I'm trying to do possible - could the `ReverseLists` method be implemented?

Comment: `sourceList` is `object`.

Comment: @Rik: Clearly that wont make the compiler happy...

Comment: If you *really* need this, try it with `List<dynamic>` as the parameter type of `ReverseLists`.

Comment: sourceList is an object - youll need some sort of cast to List to let this work

Comment: Worth noting you can make all this compile and run by abandoning generics and changing the signature of your MyReverse method to `public static void MyReverse(IList source)` (and elsewhere replace `List<object>` with `IList`) I appreciate this isn't an answer to your question though, hence why not posted as one!

Comment: @JamesS I'm be sorely tempted to post that as an answer, it would be better than the answers we have already and IMO it's a really good solution.

Comment: @Rawling - ok, posted as an answer then :)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have a static method like this

```
public static class ReverseHelper
{
    public static void MyReverse<T>(IList<T> source)
    {
        var length = source.Count;
        var hLength = length / 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < hLength; i++)
        {
            T temp = source[i];
            source[i] = source[length - 1 - i];
            source[length - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

With the help of non generic interface and a generic class you can do it.

```
public interface IReverser
{
    void Reverse();
}
public class ListReverser<T> : IReverser
{
    private readonly IList<T> source;
    public ListReverser(IList<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public void Reverse()
    {
        ReverseHelper.MyReverse<T>(source);
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lists = new List<IReverser>
    {
        new ListReverser<Foo>(new List<Foo>()),
        new ListReverser<Bar>(new List<Bar>()),
        new ListReverser<Bar>(new List<Bar>())
    };

    foreach (var reverser in lists)
    {
        reverser.Reverse();
    }
}
```

I've used `IList<T>` as opposed to `List<T>` to support broader number of types; If you want `List<T>` you can put it back.

Comment: IMO this is the neatest option.

Answer (score 7):

As per my comment above...

The compiler cannot covert infer the type of T when passed `object` (which is effectively what's happening)

However there is a much simpler option - which is to just abandon using generics, and change the signature of your MyReverse method to `public static void MyReverse(IList source)` (and elsewhere replace `List<object>` with `IList`)

ie:

```
public static void Main(string args[])
{
    var lists = new List<IList>
    {
        new List<Foo>(),
        new List<Bar>(),
        new List<Bar>()
    };

    ReverseLists(lists);
}

public static void MyReverse(IList source)
{
    var length = source.Count;
    var hLength = length / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < hLength; i++)
    {
        var temp = source[i];
        source[i] = source[length - 1 - i];
        source[length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}

public static void ReverseLists(List<IList> sourceLists)
{
    foreach (var sourceList in sourceLists)
    {
        MyReverse(sourceList); // Error: Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage
    }
}
public class Foo
{
}
public class Bar
{
}
```

Comment: I just started writing this up. I'm glad you beat me to it. This has taught me that `IList` isn't just a holdover from the pre-generic days.

Comment: This will introduce unnecessary boxing and unboxing in case of value types.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your ReverseLists method signature to

```
public static void ReverseLists<T>(IEnumerable<object> sourceLists)
{
    foreach (var sourceList in sourceLists.OfType<List<T>>())
    {
        MyReverse(sourceList);
    }
}
```

Then you can call this for each list type:

```
ReverseLists<Foo>(lists);
ReverseLists<Bar>(lists);
```

Maybe not ideal having to call it once per list type, but a comparatively small change to your existing code.

Comment: @Nathan: Ah - now I got it: You call `ReverseLists<T>` on the same list for all possible types and each "run" that type is reversed. That *would* work, but you would need to run it for every type: What if there are many different types in the list not just 2 - there it would start to get messy...

Comment: @ChrFin Indeed - as per my last line in the answer text :)

Answer (score 2):

To compliment the answer from Sriram Sakthivel - the key to your problem is that the Type cannot be inferred from what you are passing in. It's worth noting that `List<T>` implements `IList` so your issue above can be reframed using a parameter array of List like:

```
void Main()
{
    var fooList = new List<string>();
    var barList = new List<string>();
    var bazList = new List<string>();
    ReverseLists(fooList, barList, bazList);
}

public static void ReverseLists(params IList [] sourceLists)
{
    foreach (var sourceList in sourceLists)
    {
        MyReverse(sourceList); 
    }
}

public static void MyReverse(IList source)
{
    var length = source.Count;
    var hLength = length / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < hLength; i++)
    {
        var temp = source[i];
        source[i] = source[length - 1 - i];
        source[length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line in the original post:

```
MyReverse(sourceList); // Error: Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage
```

to this:

```
MyReverse(((System.Collections.IList)sourceList).Cast<object>().ToList());
```